# How do you print out the exact text "{{text}}" in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

How do you print out "{{text}}" in a Django template?  If I type it into a Django html template it gets interpreted as the variable text.  I want the actual text:

```
{{text}}
```

To appear in the html output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To output the characters used to compose template tags, you have to use a specific template tag called `templatetag`. If you want to output the `{{` characters, for example, you use `{% openvariable %}` and the output of that template tag would be `{{`.

So for your example,

```
{% openvariable %} text {% closevariable %}
```

would output:

```
{{ text }}
```

Comment: vitorbal has the correct, book answer. If you're going to do this a lot and want to reduce the number of (template) characters involved, you could write a template context processor that adds two bindings, "odb" (open double-brace) for "{{" and "cdb" for "}}". This lets you write `{{odb}}text{{cdb}}`.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use the [templatetag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) tag. However, if i recall correctly, using `{{ "{{text}}" }}` will also work, this is however undocumented behaviour, so there is no real guarantee this will never break.